# Auto Click Detection

Tags: web, click, mouse, auto

I play an online browser game and I am using an auto click program to click on a specific area regularly (Every 20-25 min). However, the game detects it. Is there any way that I can avoid the game to detect my mouse action?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the DevTools JS sources for any human-readable names related to AC detection. For example, for Cookie Clicker:

```html
if (now-Game.lastClick<(1000/15))
{
  Game.autoclickerDetected+=Game.fps;
  if (Game.autoclickerDetected>=Game.fps*5) Game.Win('Uncanny clicker');
}
```

The snippet I added above is about CPS, not precise clicks.

Check if the game has a vulnerable variable related to the threshold of timing and accuracy, you can then modify the code using UserScripts.

If the program is written in Webpack or Wasm, it won't be possible to alter the code, unless you have programs to decompile the bundle.js. DevTools should tell you if the game uses Webpack or any other bundlers.

Try to vary the clicking and the accuracy in terms of the radius of deviance from the center of the button.